# How to print a page with more attractive way

Tags: html, forms

I have a web page to print the customers for each each company has.
For instance the comany name is A. A has 4 customers and A wants to print its customers' detailed list to A4 page. On the other hand the comany B has 75 customers. Each customer, doesn't matter belong to which company, may have different size of detais.

```
COMPANY A FORM

Customer1 DETAIL1 DETAIL2 DETAIL3 ...
          *****   ***     ***
          **      **      ***
          ***
Customer2 DETAIL1 DETAIL2 DETAIL3 ...
          *****   ***     ***
          **      **      ***
          ***
Customer3 DETAIL1 DETAIL2 DETAIL3 ...
          *****   ***     ***
          **      **      ***
          *** 
          *****   ***    ***
          **      **     ***
          ***
```

You see that the customers have more information in any detail colomn.

- So when I print the page, what kind of rules or details shoul I consider to have a nice print out. What I mean; to avoid cutting the details suddenly in the middle of The Customer3's Detail 1 colomn..

Wish you get what I want.
Regards
BK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting A Specific Page Break
Maybe it's better not to have every H2 break the page. Maybe you'd like a page break at a specific point to keep a particular look. You do that by setting up a class of page breaks.
     You can set up the class on any HTML command, but I think the best method is to set up the class within a 
 or

command. That way there's some white space where the page can break. Here's a look at the format (this will sit between your  tags):

P.breakhere {page-break-before: always}

This then will be the activator for the page break: